# Distributional equality and independence

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables. Assume that 
\begin{align}
P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A) \, P(X \in B).
\end{align}
Claim: Then, $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution and independent of each other.

I agree with this intuitively but would be interested in a rigorous explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A =\mathbb R$ to see that $P(Y \in B)=P(X \in B)$. Hence $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. We now get $P(X \in A, Y \in B)=P(X\in A) P(Y \in B)$ so $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! I missed the obvious there. (Will accept the answer as soon as I can).